# How stack operation is performed via 64-Bit Flat, Paged-Memory Model in long mode i.e. 64 bit mode?

Tags: operating-system, stack, x86-64

AS we know TSS does not store general purpose registers and CR3 in long.

How general purpose registers and parameters are saved and restored?

And its hard for me to understand how stack operation is performed in long mode, please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question needs a bit more clarity. What architecture are you talking about?

For the save/restore issue, you may want to search the net for Procedure Calling Convention on the architecture that you need. For ex, here is one for AMD64 from CMU: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15213-s07/misc/asm64-handout.pdf

Comment: IA-32e 64 bit processor, 64 bit long mode architecture.